# Angular: Show hide a row based on a value in the previous row

Tags: html, angular, typescript, html-table, angular-ng-if

I am trying to hide and show based on the `<td>` value in the row in my angular 7 application. In the below example, there are three rows with the following headers.

**Component**

```js
public ColumnNames: string[] = ['Legal Class Name', 'Last Edited' , 'Legal Class ID'];
```

If you notice in the code, I am trying to hide a row based on the following condition. What I am looking for is that the row should be hidden based on the value in Last Edited row. So I need to show ColumnNames[2] if the value is true in   Last Edited

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="c != ColumnNames[2]">
```

**HTML**

```html
<table class="fundClassesTable table-striped" border="1">
  <tr *ngFor="let c of ColumnNames">
    <ng-container *ngIf="c != ColumnNames[2]">
      <th class="tableItem bold">{{ c }}</th>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let f of data">

        <ng-container>        
          <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[0]">{{f.Description}}</td>
          <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[1]">{{f.AuditSummary}}</td>
          <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[2]">{{f.Id}}</td>
        </ng-container>

      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Updated screenshot**

[image]

Comment: **HTML**: call a function in `*ngIf`, pass it the row's index... **TS**: check the previous index for your condition and pass true/false;

Comment: I am not too sure what you meant. I have created a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nc8kjofr/1/. could you kindly show me

Comment: ideal outcome should be ?

Comment: So take the first column for example. If the value in Last Edited is true then row needs to be hidden if it false then it should be shown

Comment: To be more clear, if the value is true in any of the td in that row then show the row else hide the row

Comment: Don't say ambiguous words row/column here causing confusions, do you want to hide **Class X** if `Last Edited` i.e `AuditSummary` is true? [Like this](https://jsfiddle.net/monim67/53tgweso/)?

Comment: If lastedited contains true , it could be value falling under any class then legal class id should be hidden . The entire row. I am referring to visual row as seen in the example

Comment: Shared the a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vzc4j3rs/4/ and also see the screenshot for an updated screenshot

Comment: @Tom you want to hide legal classid entire row if any of last edited is true

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason why you had a horizontal table? it just made the HTML a little weird. However, the following solution will get you what you wanted... a function is returning true/false which toggles the visibility via `*ngIf`.

relevant **TS**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  public ColumnNames: string[] = ['Legal Class Name', 'Last Edited', 'Legal Class ID'];
  data: any[] = [
    { className: 'class A', edited: 'true', id: '11101' }, { className: 'class B', edited: 'false', id: '11101' },
    { className: 'class C', edited: 'true', id: '11101' }, { className: 'class C', edited: 'true', id: '11101' },
    { className: 'class E', edited: 'true', id: '11101' }, { className: 'class D', edited: 'true', id: '11101' },
    { className: 'class G', edited: 'true', id: '11101' }, { className: 'class E', edited: 'true', id: '11101' },
    { className: 'class I', edited: 'true', id: '11101' }, { className: 'class F', edited: 'true', id: '11101' },
    { className: 'class K', edited: 'true', id: '11101' }, { className: 'class G', edited: 'true', id: '11101' },
  ]
  constructor() { }

  checkVisibility() {
    let columnCheck: boolean = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
      if (this.data[i].edited == 'false') {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return columnCheck;
  }
}
```

relevant **HTML**:

```
<h3>
    Vertical Table
</h3>

<table class="fundClassesTable table-striped" border="1">
    <thead>
        <th class="tableItem bold">{{ColumnNames[0]}}</th>
        <th class="tableItem bold">{{ColumnNames[1]}}</th>
        <th class="tableItem bold" *ngIf='checkVisibility()'>{{ColumnNames[2]}}</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let f of data">

            <td class="tableItem">{{f.className}}</td>
            <td class="tableItem">{{f.edited}}</td>
            <td class="tableItem" *ngIf='checkVisibility()'>{{f.id}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<hr/>

    <h3>
        Horizontal Table
    </h3>
    <table class="fundClassesTable table-striped" border="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th class="tableItem bold">{{ColumnNames[0]}}</th>
                <ng-container *ngFor="let f2 of data">
                    <td class="tableItem bold">{{f2.className}}</td>
                </ng-container>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="tableItem bold">{{ColumnNames[1]}}</th>
                <ng-container *ngFor="let f3 of data">
                    <td class="tableItem bold">{{f3.edited}}</td>
                </ng-container>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngIf='checkVisibility()'>
                <th class="tableItem bold">{{ColumnNames[2]}}</th>
                <ng-container *ngFor="let f4 of data">
                    <td class="tableItem bold">{{f4.id}}</td>
                </ng-container>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

complete [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kfprty)

Answer (score 0):

if I am correct you want if any of the last-edit are true to hide entire legal class ID row.

by this consideration, you just have to replace this row

```
<td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[2]">{{f.Id}}</td>
```

to this:

```
<td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[2] && f.AuditSummary =='false' ">{{f.Id}}</td>
```

here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nikhil4434/jqL3rs94/) to check the behavior

Answer (score 0):

Your table template looks kind of confusing ;). The HTML standard does not expect a `table` in horizontal orientation, so to accomplish this, some tricks need to be done in any way.

Here is my solution to your task (I omitted some common code lines):

- It is a bit more code, but this is for more readability and maintainability (in my opinion).
- It is also less performance intensive than some other solutions, since the data is iterated only once.
- The most logic is done in code-behind, not in the template.

[Live example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a4cghe)

**app.component.ts:**

```ts
import { MyType } from './my-table/my-table.component';

// @Component ...
export class AppComponent  {
  myData: MyType[] = [
    { legalClassName: 'Class A', lastEdited: false, legalClassID: '11167' },
    { legalClassName: 'Class B', lastEdited: false, legalClassID: '13717' }
  ];
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<my-table [data]="myData"></my-table>
```

**my-table.component.ts**

```ts
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

export class MyType {
  legalClassName: string;
  lastEdited: boolean;
  legalClassID: string;
}

class HorizontalTableColumn {
  header: string;
  visible: boolean;
  items: any[];
}

// @Component ...
export class MyTableComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input()
  data: MyType[];

  columnsThatAreActuallyRows: HorizontalTableColumn[] = [
    { header: 'Legal Class Name', visible: true, items: [] },
    { header: 'Last Edited',      visible: true, items: [] },
    { header: 'Legal Class ID',   visible: true, items: [] }
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.processData();
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.processData();
  }

  private processData() {
    this.columnsThatAreActuallyRows[0].items = [];
    this.columnsThatAreActuallyRows[1].items = [];
    this.columnsThatAreActuallyRows[2].items = [];

    let newVal = this.data;
    if (newVal != undefined && newVal != null && newVal.length > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < newVal.length; i++) {
        let item = newVal[i] as MyType;

        this.columnsThatAreActuallyRows[0].items.push(item.legalClassName);
        this.columnsThatAreActuallyRows[1].items.push(item.lastEdited);
        this.columnsThatAreActuallyRows[2].items.push(item.legalClassID);

        if (item.LastEdited) {
          this.columnsThatAreActuallyRows[2].visible = false;
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

**my-table.component.html**

```html
<table>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let fakeCol of columnsThatAreActuallyRows"> 
    <tr *ngIf="fakeCol.visible">
      <th>{{fakeCol.header}}</th>
      <td *ngFor="let item of fakeCol.items">{{item}}</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```